# Xsd, Validate empty or minimum length string

Tags: xsd, xml-validation

Currently I have an Xsd validating with this rule

```
<xs:simpleType name='shipTo'>
    <xs:restriction base='xs:string'>
        <xs:minLength value='6'/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

I need to allow blanks as well, but if a value is entered, it's minimum length should still be 6.

Can I do this without resorting to this `xs:pattern` and regex?

```
<xs:simpleType name='shipTo'>
    <xs:restriction base='xs:string'>
        <xs:pattern value='^(?:|[\w]{6,})$'/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regex will work, but you should really make the element that you will be assigning `shipTo` to optional, and not include it in the XML file if it has no value.

Comment: Yeah, that would make more sense.  Unfortunately, I don't control the consumer of said xml...which is not written well.